# What are the red strips and the "*" signs mean in Aptana 3?

Tags: html, aptana, aptana3

what does these signs mean?

[image: Aptana printscreen]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends from your configuration, as these kind of settings are theme-specific, however I would guess they signal the file on disk has changed relative to either:

1. The beginning of the working session
2. The last committed version (if you are using a versioning system)

HTH!

Answer (score 16):

Evidently Aptana "helps" you by assuming that you're working with a team and so marks any files you've changed as requiring check in.

The way I cleared this was: right-click the Aptana project folder, choose Team, then choose Disconnect.

Cheers & hope this helps,
Riley
SFO

Comment: the files still don't seem to appear in file system

Comment: @Riley Perfect answer indeed , but there is no reason why aptana studio to think that everyone is working as a theme.. LOL

Answer (score 6):

Its basically suggesting that the current version has changed from last time. However this can be switched off from the following location -
Window/Preferences, General/Appearance/Label Decorations.
Depending on what source repository you use, unchecking "Git Decorator" for example would turn this feature off.

Comment: Voted for yours as the problem has to do with Git for me, it's useful but annoying when it's on all the time. Thanks Shikhar

Answer (score 2):

Is your project under source / version control?  If so, those types of indications usually indicate modified files that have not yet been committed back to the repository.